# enforce package order when installing with pip using a wheel file

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, python-packaging

I have a python `requirements.txt` file as follows:

```
torch==1.0.0
torchvision==0.2.1
opencv_python==3.4.2.17
numpy==1.15.1
gputil==1.3.0
scikit_learn==0.19.2
scikit_image==0.14.0
sk_video==1.1.10
git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark.git@5ec0b91cc85163ac3b58265b3f9b39bb327d0ba6
```

Firstly, I generate a wheel file as follows:

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=wheels --no-deps .
```

Then I install it as:

```
pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt --find-links=./wheels
```

However, no matter where I put the `git` project in my `requirements.txt` file, it is always the first thing `pip` tries to install. This is problematic as the other packages need to be installed first. How can I specify or enforce some order in the package installation?

Comment: Properly define the dependencies in the `setup.py` of `maskrcnn-benchmark`.

Comment: Why are you generating a release (wheel file) if you are going to install directly from a git hash?  These are conflicting directions...

Comment: @KlausD Is it possible to specify dependency in my own setup.py file instead of cloning the maskrcnn project?

Comment: That would not fix the installatuob order problem. And frankly it's Github, you can fork the project with one click.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you. Yes, certainly github makes it easy. However, how can I specify the dependencies in the `setup.py` file? Do they somehow not have to be specified outside? The `install_requires` section only specified the requirements at run time but I want to specify install dependencies and install order? There is a `setup_requires` flag but most docs say not to use it....

Comment: @KlausD. I managed to get it working by setitng the install_requires. Please feel free to write your comment as an answer. Thank you again!